# Parsing request body in a Chrome extension listener returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am building a Chrome extension that extracts user data from a registration form on a website. I have set up a listener to intercept the form data, but when I try to retrieve the user's first and last name using FormData, it returns "undefined".

Here's the relevant code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Extract user data from a registration form",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.url.includes("https://www.example.com/register/")) {
      const form = new FormData(details.requestBody.formData);
      const userFirstName = form.get('firstName');
      const userLastName = form.get('LastName');
      console.log(`First name: ${userFirstName}, Last name: ${userLastName}`);
    }
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"] },
  ["requestBody"]
);
```

**The Error from the console**

[image]

I have confirmed that the listener is working and intercepting the form data, but I can't seem to retrieve the user's first and last name. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FormData can be constructed only from a DOM form but `formData` is a plain object, so this code won't work. Instead you should access the object directly, without FormData. You can also use breakpoints in devtools debugger to inspect the object interactively to know what you're dealing with.

Comment: I tried using 
[const requestBody = details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes; ]
instead of 
[const form = new FormData(details.requestBody);]
 but I'm still getting an error that says: 
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'raw') in the event handler.

Comment: It's an old error. Click the trashcan icon to remove it. Generally it's the worst way of debugging. Instead, you should use the [built-in devtools debugger](/a/10258029). Also, don't use `raw`, use `formData` as an object.

Comment: I did try to debug the issue by printing the 'details' object to the console. However, I didn't see the body of the request in the output. What's more, I found it strange that the listener is triggered for a GET request rather than a POST request, which is the one that actually runs the user registration process.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgYum.png

Comment: onBeforeRequest is triggered for all requests indeed, so you need to add a check for details.method and other possibly relevant things.

Comment: I added a statement to check if the request method is "POST" like this:
    if (details.method === "POST")
However, I'm still getting the same object as before when I debug it with the console. Is there anything else that I might be missing?

Comment: Maybe you didn't reload the extension after editing or the changes didn't apply due to a bug in Chrome. Inspect the code in devtools debugger and look at the actual code, set breakpoints, and see what actually happens when the event is triggered.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling my extension after modifying the code, but upon inspecting with the devtools debugger, I found that only GET requests were being caught while POST requests were not. Moreover, the content type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so I don't think the issue stems from there.

Comment: Maybe the page uses XMLHttpRequest to post the data. Try removing `types` parameter or add `'xmlhttprequest'` to the list.

Comment: I managed to make it work! It turns out that I was looking for the wrong URL. Instead of 'https://example.com/register', I was looking for 'https://example.com/register//'. The only way for me to spot this mistake was by using the DevTools. Thanks!